# Connecting to IMAP using Javamail on other systems

Tags: java, imap, jakarta-mail

I am using this code in my project to connect to the inbox of Gmail as well as my uni mail. It works fine on my system and i can connect to the IMAP of both. But as soon as try the same code on other systems, Gmail gets a connection time out. It is not able to connect. I searched a bit and found out that my system is listening to the port 443 whereas on the other system i tested on, it was not listening to port 443. I tried to give some inbound rules in the other system to open the 443 port but as soon as i run my prog it gets blocked.

Is this problem due to the port? Or am i missing something here?

```
public class MailConnection {
    Folder inbox;

public MailConnection() throws MessagingException{
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imap");
    try{
       Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
       Store store = session.getStore("imap");
       store.connect("mailbox.xyz.com", "emailId@xyz.com", "password");
       System.out.println(store);

       inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");
       System.out.println("No of Unread Messages : " + inbox.getUnreadMessageCount());
    }
    catch (NoSuchProviderException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're connecting to the non-SSL IMAP port - 143.  I don't know where "443" comes from.

Gmail needs the SSL IMAP port.  See [this JavaMail FAQ entry](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#gmail) for an example.

If it doesn't work, see [these debugging tips](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug).

Comment: I don't understand one thing that how the non-SSL code work on my development system and not work on test system?

Comment: gmail does not support non-SSL connections to IMAP.  Your university system might.

Comment: @Max - what i meant was that i am able to connect to Gmail by non-SSL on my development system. But it fails in the test system. Moreover the SSL connection to Gmail works in the test system but not in my development system.... strange isn't it ?

Comment: I have no idea how non-SSL is possible.  Gmail does not listen on port 143, as they (correctly) believe it is a security hazard.  Perhaps you have some local transparent proxy?  Or a firewall rule that sends it to some other server?

Comment: @Max - Gmail is not connecting to the SSL IMAP port on some systems. But on some systems it works. Do you have any idea why and how can i fix this?

Comment: Well according to Google and through extensive use of it, they only support connections to the IMAP server on port 993. You can always use a tool like socat or the like to test your network systems before coding them up in Java.

Comment: The JavaMail FAQ has [tips for debugging connection problems](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug).